# Strange error with express and cradle

Tags: node.js, couchdb, coffeescript, cradle

I can't explain any better, because I honestly have no idea why this error exists. First off, here is the code where I get the error:

```
app.get '/image/:id', (req, res, next) ->
    images.get req.params.id, (err, doc) ->
        if err then next err else
            res.contentType doc._attachments.image.content_type
            img = images.getAttachment doc.id, 'image'
            img.on 'data', (chunk) ->
                res.write chunk, 'binary'
            img.on 'end', ->
                res.end()
```

I am fairly sure the problem must be in there somewhere. I have an `/upload` route that redirects to this, to show the uploaded image right away.

And then I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
    at Object.lookup (/home/scan/Javascript/acres/node_modules/express/node_modules/mime/mime.js:62:20)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (/home/scan/Javascript/acres/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:209:43)
    at Object.callback (/home/scan/Javascript/acres/app.coffee:105:13)
    at Object.get (/home/scan/Javascript/acres/node_modules/cradle/lib/cradle.js:316:33)
    at /home/scan/Javascript/acres/app.coffee:100:19
    at callbacks (/home/scan/Javascript/acres/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
    at param (/home/scan/Javascript/acres/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
    at param (/home/scan/Javascript/acres/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:243:11)
    at pass (/home/scan/Javascript/acres/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/scan/Javascript/acres/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:4)
```

Of course I wanted to look up what value exactly is giving me the trouble, so I changed the code with some `console.log` in every nesting. `nodemon` restarted the app, and it works like a charm, for this image. With this code.

So I upload another, exactly the same error. Code change, restart, works for this image.

So where do I go wrong or do I have to restart on every upload?

**EDIT**: Some info about the system:

```
connect-cradle@0.1.0
connect-form@0.2.1
cradle@0.5.7
express@2.4.6
node@0.4.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the second line in the call stack:

> at ServerResponse.contentType (/home/scan/Javascript/acres/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:209:43)

So the error is occurring in your `res.contentType` call, which passes `doc._attachments.image.content_type` to `mime.lookup`, which calls `.replace` on it. In short, the problem is that `doc._attachments.image.content_type` is undefined.

I hope that at least gets you started in your debugging efforts.

Comment: So could it be that the image is not completely uploaded to CouchDB, but the callcack of `saveAttachment` was already called? But then, why is the `content_type` not set until I restart the server?

Comment: Try down `console.log JSON.stringify(doc._attachments.image)` to see its state. Is it possible that the `images.getAttachment` call is causing the database to set `content_type`? In that case, all you'd have to do is switch those two lines.

Comment: No, that did not help either. I had suspected the caching to be the problem, but it was switched off all the way. The content type seems to be properly set. You know what, I will just switch to mongo, instead.

Comment: I solved it by saving the mime type in the document rather than the attachment. That seemed to help.